# How to change line width in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

Datalink:
[the data used](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yt4l10nel5bwxoq/GTAP_ConsIndex.csv)

My code:

```
ccfsisims <- read.csv(file = "F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/GTAP-CGE/GTAP_NewAggDatabase/NewFiles/GTAP_ConsIndex.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
ccfsirsts <- as.data.frame(ccfsisims)
ccfsirsts[6:24] <- sapply(ccfsirsts[6:24],as.numeric)
ccfsirsts <- droplevels(ccfsirsts)
ccfsirsts <- transform(ccfsirsts,sres=factor(sres,levels=unique(sres)))

library(ggplot2)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#### Plot of food security index for Morocco and Turkey by sector
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#_Code_Begin...

datamortur <- melt(ccfsirsts[ccfsirsts$region %in% c("TUR","MAR"), ]) # Selecting regions of interest
datamortur1 <- datamortur[datamortur$variable %in% c("pFSI2"), ] # Selecting the food security index of interest
datamortur2 <- datamortur1[datamortur1$sector %in% c("wht","gro","VegtFrut","osd","OthCrop","VegtOil","XPrFood"), ] # Selecting food sectors of interest
datamortur3 <- subset(datamortur2, tradlib !="BASEDATA") # Eliminating the "BASEDATA" scenario results  

allfsi.f <- datamortur3
fsi.wht <- allfsi.f[allfsi.f$sector %in% c("wht"), ]

Figure29 <- ggplot(data=fsi.wht, aes(x=factor(sres),y=value,colour=factor(tradlib)))
Figure29 + geom_line(aes(group=factor(tradlib),size=2)) + facet_grid(regionsFull~., scales="free_y", labeller=reg_labeller) + scale_colour_brewer(type = "div") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black', angle = 90, size = 13, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),axis.title.x=element_blank()) + 
ylab("FSI (%Change)") + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 12), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.2)) + 
theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 11, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'))
```

My result:
[image: Result_Figure]

Newresult with aes(size=2):
[image: NewResult-Figure]

My question:
Is there a way to control for line width more precisely to avoid the result in the second plot? I particularly find it document-unfriendly, and more so for publishing purposes to include the plot with the newly defined line width.

best,
ismail

Comment: To change line width, just add argument size=2 to geom_line().

Comment: Just did some experimentation and it looks like size doesn't have to assume integral values as you're using with 1 and 2. I just entered 1.5 and got something in-between. I'm not sure if a fixed value like that would work for you under all circumstances but it does appear tunable at least.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Whilst @Didzis has the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796845/1385941), I will expand on a few points

Aesthetics can be set or mapped within a ggplot call.

- An aesthetic defined within aes(...) is mapped from the data, and a legend created.
- An aesthetic may also be set to a single value, by defining it outside aes().

As far as I can tell, what you want is to *set* size to a single value, not *map* within the call to `aes()`

When you call `aes(size = 2)` it creates a variable called `` `2` `` and uses that to create the size, mapping it from a constant value as it is within a call to `aes` (thus it appears in your legend).

Using size = 1 (and without `reg_labeller` which is perhaps defined somewhere in your script)

```
Figure29 +
    geom_line(aes(group=factor(tradlib)),size=1) +
    facet_grid(regionsFull~., scales="free_y") +
    scale_colour_brewer(type = "div") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
          colour = 'black', angle = 90, size = 13,
          hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
    ylab("FSI (%Change)") +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 12), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, 
          hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.2)) + 
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 11, hjust = 0.5,
          vjust =    0.5, face = 'bold'))
```

[image]

and with size = 2

```
 Figure29 + 
     geom_line(aes(group=factor(tradlib)),size=2) +
     facet_grid(regionsFull~., scales="free_y") + 
     scale_colour_brewer(type = "div") +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black', angle = 90,
          size = 13, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 
          0.5),axis.title.x=element_blank()) + 
     ylab("FSI (%Change)") +
     theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 12),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12,
          hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.2)) + 
      theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 11, hjust = 0.5,
          vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'))
```

[image]

You can now define the size to work appropriately with the final image size and device type.

Comment: Great answer. Update with ggplot3.4.0, the new argument is `linewidth` instead of `size`.

Answer (score 97):

Line width in `ggplot2` can be changed with argument `size=` in `geom_line()`.

```r
# sample data
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I have already tried your option, but the problem is that the line become too thick to be considered document-friendly. When using the aes(size), I get the second graph that I added. I want to be able to control for the width in a more systematic way so as to choose the best fit.

Comment: @smailov83, don't put size within the call to `aes`. See my answer (or the `ggplot2` book for an explanation.

Comment: Default value seems to be less than `size=1`, maybe `0.5`, so using `size=1` yields quite good results in my opinion. One can also use decimal numbers to fine tune the width (say `size=1.2`).

Comment: Note that from [ggplot2 3.4.0](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html), `size` is superseded for lines and is now replaced by the more explicit `linewidth`.

Answer (score 15):

Line width in `ggplot2` can be changed with argument `lwd=` in `geom_line()`.

```
geom_line(aes(x=..., y=..., color=...), lwd=1.5)
```

Comment: worked for me today in geom_hline where "size=" is not recognized

Comment: I believe the argument is called `linewidth` in current versions of ggplot. Also `lineend="square"` extends the line while `"butt"` only increases width.

Answer (score 10):

It also looks like if you just put the `size` argument in the `geom_line()` portion but without the `aes()` it will scale appropriately. At least it works this way with `geom_density` and I had the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify the line width flexibly you can use "scale_size_manual," this is the same procedure for picking the color, fill, alpha, etc.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

x = seq(0,10,0.05)

df <- data.frame(A = 2 * x + 10,
                 B = x**2 - x*6,
                 C = 30 - x**1.5,
                 X = x)


df = gather(df,A,B,C,key="Model",value="Y")


ggplot( df, aes (x=X, y=Y, size=Model, colour=Model ))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_size_manual( values = c(4,2,1) ) +
  scale_color_manual( values = c("orange","red","navy") )
```

Answer (score 4):

Since ggplot2 3.4.0. use `linewidth`.

For example:

```
geom_line(aes(group=factor(tradlib)), linewidth=0.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the size command *outside* the aes() function, with any fractional value desired, e.g. size = 1.5

```
geom_line(data,aes(x=x,y=y), size=1.5)
```