# Increase the size of line in geom_line

Tags: r

This is the code I am using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Date1, group=1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Wet, colour = "Wet")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Dry, colour = "Dry"))
```

When I use the function size, the lines are too thick and their width is identical from `size=0.1` to `size=10` or more. Is there a way to control the size of the line?

Dummy data:

```
Date         Wet    Dry
July        5.65    4.88
September   5.38    3.93
October     4.73    2.42
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How the change line width in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794599/how-the-change-line-width-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 5):

One issue that is commonly run into when changing the size using geom_line() is that the size must go OUTSIDE of the aes() commands.  If you don't do that, the size argument will always keep the lines at an obnoxious size.

So, instead of:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Date1, group=1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Wet, colour = "Wet", size = 3)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Dry, colour = "Dry", size = 3))
```

Try:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Date1, group=1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Wet, colour = "Wet"), size = 3) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Dry, colour = "Dry"), size = 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself adding multiple `geom_line` statements, it's because you need to convert your data from wide to long, *i.e.* one column for variable (Wet/Dry) and another for its values. Then `ggplot` takes care of everything itself.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  gather(condition, value, -Date) %>% 
  mutate(Date = factor(Date, 
                       levels = c("July", "September", "October"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = condition, group = condition), size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update: "Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
i Please use `linewidth` instead."

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Date1, group=1)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = Wet, colour = "Wet"), linewidth= 3) + 
geom_line(aes(y = Dry, colour = "Dry"), linewidth= 3)
```

Note that you might have to engage in trial and error if you also want to change the `linetype`. e.g. see [Change line width in ggplot, not size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885265/change-line-width-in-ggplot-not-size)